# Azure Durable Function : When chaining multiple functions new instances start before any message can finish processing

Tags: c#, azure, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Durable function with a QueueTrigger. And internally I have a few Azure functions which get invoked along with sub-orchestration. Here's the code

```
 var processKatartItem = context.GetInput<KatartItem>();

if (!processKatartItem.ProcessLeadTime && !processKatartItem.ProcessPrice && !processKatartItem.ProcessStock)
{
    await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("LLGFeedPreProductMessageProcessor", new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5), processKatartItem);
}

var tasks = new Task[processKatartItem.vardatas.Count];

for (var i = 0; i < processKatartItem.vardatas.Count; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = context.CallSubOrchestratorWithRetryAsync("LLGFeedProductOrchestrator", new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5), new ProductProcessingModel
    {
        ProcessKatartItem = processKatartItem,
        ProcessVardata = processKatartItem.vardatas[i]
    });
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("LLGFeedFinalizeMessage", new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5), processKatartItem);
```

And here's the code for the SubOrchestrator

```
var processModel = context.GetInput<ProductProcessingModel>();

await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("LLGFeedProductSpecificationProcessor", new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5), processModel);
await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("LLGFeedProductMessageProcessor", new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5), processModel);
await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("LLGFeedProductMappingProcessor", new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5), processModel);
await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("LLGFeedProductPriceProcessor", new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5), processModel);
```

The way this is structured, we process the message and its subinputs into the database and then run the MessageFinalization which indexes the message/product into Elastic Search by calling an Api on our WebSite. We queue in a lot of messages and then process it.

The problem I'm having is that the Durable Function executes the first few Azure functions and then waits on the last few.
 Here's a screenshot from the WebJobs Dashboard

[image]

SO as you can see a lot of messages have been processed but not 1 instance for the LLGFeedFinalizeMessage has been executed. Is there way I can ensure my entire pipeline gets executed instead of first few functions first and all the functions at the end later. Or maybe even FIFO. That is make the orchestrator to wait and finish all its functions before a new instance gets fired up.

Host.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
      "durableTask": {
        "HubName": "LLGFeedTaskHub",
        "ControlQueueBatchSize": 8,
        "PartitionCount": 2,
        "MaxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 10,
        "MaxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 2,
        "AzureStorageConnectionStringName": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
      },
      "queues": {
        "batchSize": 10,
        "newBatchThreshold": 5
      }
    },
    "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for this? I think the power of serverless durable functions is that you get concurrent orchestrator executions.

Comment: @MarieHoeger While that is true, I want to ensure that the durable function doesnt DDOS our website. The last function call will call an Web Api Endpoint on our website. And even though I've throttled the Durable function to run only 2 orchestrators and 10 Activities concurrently, it looks like at the end there will be huge batch of the webapi calls excuted (around 10 at a time).

Comment: Have you tried tweaking your [QueueTrigger's settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#host-json) to lower the rate of orchestrations being created?

Comment: @KatyShimizu I've shared my host.json

Comment: I'm just throwing things out here (and have not tested the behavior of this app setting with durable), but this may be relevant? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#websitemaxdynamicapplicationscaleout

Comment: Cheers. I'll experiment..

Comment: Katy also pointed me to Singletons for Durable Functions which will get you one orchestration at a time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-singletons. This is more work though and the app settings we pointed to you may be enough for your scenario!

Comment: @MarieHoeger The application settings did not work https://imgur.com/a/MiczWdm I'll try the singleton example

Comment: @MarieHoeger The singleton attribute didnt work. I was able to implement what I wanted using a ServiceBus. I'll share the design in sometime